# How to retrieve a sound from a SQLite database?

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

i want to retrieve the sound once I clicked on the button. The sound is retrieved from sqlite database in BLOB form. I have included the source code below. Anyone can help to correct my coding.

I already tried to retrieve the sound using file but i got an error which java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.io.File.

```
/*databaseAccess.java*/
public List<byte[]> getAudio(long i) 
{
    List<byte[]> list = new ArrayList<>();

    byte[] byteaudio = null;
    String selectAudio = "SELECT audio FROM IMAGE WHERE id =" + i;
    Cursor c = database.rawQuery(selectAudio, null);
    if(c.moveToFirst())
        do{
            byteaudio = c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("audio"));
            list.add(byteaudio);
        }while(c.moveToNext());

    return list;
}

/*MainActivity.java*/
public void playSong(int songIndex) {

    // Define final variables since they have to be accessed from inner class
    final DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this);

    // Open the database
    databaseAccess.open();

    // Close the database
    databaseAccess.close();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    long topicId = intent.getLongExtra("SelectedTopicId", 0);

    databaseAccess.open();
    List<byte[]> audio = databaseAccess.getAudio(songIndex);
    databaseAccess.close();

    mp.reset();
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, Uri.fromFile((File) audio));// create's

    mp.start(); // starting mediaplayer

}
```

Comment: why dont you store your audio data in audio files? why do you have to use BLOBs?

Comment: `Uri.fromFile((File) audio)` cannot work. In fact, creating a URI from a list of `byte[]` doesn't even make any sense.

Comment: You should probably implement a [`MediaDataSource`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaDataSource) which provides access to your `byte[]`s of audio data, then use [`MediaPlayer.setDataSource()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource(android.media.MediaDataSource)) to pass it to the media player.

Comment: Storing BLOBS is a **worst practice**.

Comment: @pskink how to store in audio files? is the files will be connected to sqlite database? because the sound is specific to particular image.

Comment: @JimmyB can you give any coding example for it?

Comment: Instead of audio data you can store only the audio files' *names* in the database...

Comment: Where are you struggling in implementing the one single method of your custom `MediaDataSource`?

Comment: @JimmyB how to store  audio file name in dtabase? as for now, i only can upload it in binary form. If i store it in text or image form the audio doesnt appear in column